# Equal multiples of a nonzero vector implies equal factors

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space with zero element and let $v \in V$. Suppose $av = bv$ and $v \neq 0$.  Show that $a = b$.

Anyone can guide me on this?  Thank you!

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Scalars or elements of $V$?

Comment: @algebraic pavel scalars

Comment: Re: "vector space with zero element": Do you know of any vector spaces without?

Comment: @marc van leeuwen haha true.ques stated in that way anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space with zero element $0$.  Let $v \in V$.

Now assume that $av = bv$ and $v \neq 0$.

By linearity:

$$av = bv \Longrightarrow av - bv = 0 \Longrightarrow v(a - b) = 0.$$

Now use the assumption that $v \neq 0$ to conclude that $a = b$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you vote for me also? thx!

Comment: @user3437854, done!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $av = bv$ (I assume that $a, b$ are in your ground field), consider the element
$$
(a - b) \cdot v = a \cdot v - b \cdot v = 0
$$